# Why is Webpack looking for a preset in my home directory?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, flowtype

In the Webpack for a project I'm working on, I have Webpack set to do Babel transpiling so I can use Flow-typed JavaScript. However, when I run Webpack, which has this rule,

```
  {
    test: /\.js/,
    exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
    use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['env'],
        plugins: ['transform-flow-strip-types']
      }
    }]
  }
```

I'm getting:

```
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "transform-flow-strip-types"
relative to directory "/home/andy"
```

Last time I was working on this, Webpack worked correctly and was searching for transform-flow-strip-types in my node_modules folder, but now it's looking in my home directory. Why would Webpack all of a sudden by looking in my home directory, or how would I be able to diagnose why that is?

Comment: Do you happen to have a `.babelrc` file in your home directory?

Comment: @loganfsmyth That was it! Please convert that to an answer so I can hook you up with a green checkmark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unfortunate footgun in Babel's config file parsing. It has traversed all the way out of your project and found an unrelated `.babelrc` file that is in your home directory.

There's pretty much never a reason to have a `.babelrc` there, so your best bet would be to delete `/home/andy/.babelrc`. Alternatively if that's actually something your wanted (if so, please reconsider :P), you could create a no-op `.babelrc` in your project with just an empty object in it, which would also fix the issue.

I'm currently working to make Babel stop searching for `.babelrc` files as soon as it finds any `package.json` but that has yet to land and would only apply to Babel 7.x, not the current 6.x release. https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/7358